# PHP/MySQL export then import again

Tags: php, mysql

I build a small application using PHP/MySQL. After one year of development, I fell that I need to update MySQL tables structures.

I do that using (`SELECT * INTO OUTFILE`) it is work in my local server but not in any user that host his application in hosting company that use some thing like cPanel ( or Control Panel that given by host company to let user manage his web page, emails,ftp account, database...etc).

That type of hosting is not giving full root access to any user cuz it is share same hardware with many other clients.

edit:

I forget to tell you that I need to do that using php script I made, to let ppl run it on their servers to make this automatically. there is no thing to do by user..... this script will do the following:

1) get a copy for all data in each table.

2) delete/Drop all tables.

3) create new tables with new structure.

4) import data again to that new labels.

Comment: Please try to use dots and commas and sentences. The text is hard to read. And what is CPanle?

Comment: small aplication after one year of development??((

Comment: I don't see how this deserves 2 downvotes? +1 to even out.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question repeatedly. Thanks.

Comment: markus: I add more details about cPanel.

Comment: Tural: it was a small, but now it is grown up :)

Comment: Kev: as soon as I'm new in here, I will put that in mind... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use phpMyAdmin, available from cPanel.

Comment: I know how to use that.... but I need to make a php script to do that for user that they dont know how to deal with phpMyAdmin or cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

if it's working on your local machine then it is highly likeable that the user you are using to connect to the DB does not has all the privileges required.

Comment: cuz his database in share hosting platform, it is allow to do many things.. like execute command from inside PHP... or run such query (SELECT * INTO OUTFILE)

Answer (score -1):

You can use cron jobs for regularly exporting (dumping) your databases. Also use phpmyadmin like JohnD mentioned

Comment: I downvoted it because cron jobs have nothing to do with the question